# How to let data "disappear" from database? MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a bit of a stupid question. The thing is my program has to have the function to delete data from my database. Yay, not really the problem. But how can I delete data without the danger that others can see, that there has been something deleted.

```
User Table:
U_ID  U_NAME
1     Chris
2     Peter

OTHER TABLE
ID TIMESTAMP  FK_U_D
1  2012-12-01   1
2  2012-12-02   1
```

Sooooo the ID's are AUTO_INCREMENT, so if I delete one of them there's a gap. Furthermore, the timestamp is also bigger than the row before, so ascending.

I want to let the data with ID 1 disappear from the user's profile (U_ID 1).

If I delete it, there is a gap. If I just change the FK_U_ID to 2 (Peter) it's obvious, because when I insert data, there are 20 or 30 data rows with the same U_ID...so it's obvious that there has been a modification.

If I set the FK_U_ID NULL --> same sh** like when I change it to another U_ID.

Is there any solution to get this work? I know that if nobody but me has access to the database, it's just no problem. But just in case, if somebody controls my program it should not be obvious that there has been modifications.

So here we go.

Comment: From the question: "How can i delete data without the danger that others can see".  What would be the consequences if they found out you were deleting from the database?  The amount of effort you expend to deceive is proportional to how much trouble you get into if "they" find out what your objectives are in the deception.

Comment: The ancient struggle between the deceivers and the authorities.  It's so hard to decide when to help the freedom fighters, and when to help the established judicial system.  It all depends on who is on the side of right.  The cost benefit analysis of unauthorized criminal behavior. A complex new world we are finding ourselves in. Scary stuff.

Comment: Just admit that you have made a cock up. Simpler in the long run. We all do make mistakes.

Comment: i just wanted you to know, that this is for a project of my university. showing how and if it's possible so the knowledge won't be used in production, only in test cases.

Comment: thank you for your time and advices. which one, would you suggest as the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ID gaps issue you can use [GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) as @SLaks suggests, but then you can't use the native RDBMS auto_increment which means you have to create the GUID and insert it along with the rest of the record data upon creation. Of course, you don't really need the ID to be globally unique, you could just store a random string of 20 characters or something, but then you have to do a DB read to see if that ID is taken and repeat (recursively) that process until you find an unused ID... could be quite taxing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear why you would want to "hide" evidence that a delete was performed. That sounds like a really bad idea. I'm not a fan of promulgating misinformation.

Two of the characteristics of an ideal primary key are:
 - anonymous (be void of any useful information, doesn't matter what it's set to)
 - immutable (once assigned, it will never be changed.)

But, if we set that whole discussion aside...

---

I can answer a slightly different question (an answer you might find helpful to your particular situation)

The only way to eliminate a "gap" in the values in a column with an AUTO_INCREMENT would be to change the column values from their current values to a contiguous sequence of new values. If there are any foreign keys that reference that column, the values in those columns would need to be updated as well, to preserve the relationship. That will likely leave the current auto_increment value of the table higher than the largest value of the id column, so I'd want to reset that as well, to avoid a "gap" on the next insert.

(I have done re-sequencing of auto_increment values in development and test environments, to "cleanup" lookup tables, and to move the id values of some tables to ranges that are distinct from ranges in other tables...  that let's me test SQL to make sure the SQL join predicates aren't inadvertently referencing the wrong table, and returning rows that look correct by accident... those are some reasons I've done reassignment if auto_increment values)

Note that the database can "automagically" update foreign key values (for InnnoDB tables) when you change the primary key value, as long as the foreign key constraint is defined with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, and `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` is not disabled.

If there are no foreign keys to deal with, and assuming that all of the current values of id are positive integers, then I've been able to do something like this: (with appropriate backups in place, so I can recover if things don't work right)

```
UPDATE mytable t
  JOIN (
         SELECT s.id           AS old_id
              , @i := @i + 1   AS new_id
           FROM mytable s
          CROSS
           JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) i
          ORDER BY s.id
       ) c
    ON t.id = c.old_id
   SET t.id = c.new_id
 WHERE t.id <> c.new_id
```

To reset the table AUTO_INCREMENT back down to the largest id value in the table:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Typically, I will create a table and populate it from that query in the inline view (aliased as `c`) above. I can then use that table to update both foreign key columns and the primary key column, first disabling the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS and then re-enabling it.  (In a concurrent environment, where other processes might be inserting/updating/deleting rows from one of the tables, I would of course first obtain an exclusive lock on all of the tables to be updated.)

---

Taking up again, the discussion I set aside earlier... this type of "administrative" function can be useful in a test environment, when setting up test cases. But it is NOT a function that is ever performed in a production environment, with live data.